# first index to matrix is ignored

Tags: c, matrix, symmetric, symmetry

I am trying to see if a 4x4 matrix is symmetric, and below is what i have so far. Upon compiling I receive the message:

```
pExam3p2.c:12:13: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]  
                                if (Num[r,c]==Num[c,r]){  
                                        ^
pExam3p2.c:12:23: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
                                if (Num[r,c]==Num[c,r]).
```

I thought that adding an else statement would resolve this issue. But it does not. Any ideas is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
char isSymm (int Num[][4], int rows, int cols){
    int r,c, count=0;

    for (r=0; r<rows; r++){
        for (c=0; c<cols; c++){
            if (Num[r,c]==Num[c,r]){
                count=count+1;
            }
            else{
                count=count;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count==16){
        return 'y';
    }
    else {
        return 'n';
    }
}

int main (void){
    int Num[4][4];
    int c;
    int r;
    int size =4;

    for (r=0;r<size; r++){
        for (c=0; c<size; c++){
            printf("Enter your number: ");
            scanf("%d", &Num[r][c]); //NOTE THE &...
        }
    }

    char result= isSymm(Num, 4, 4);
    printf("%c", result);
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using modern C tricks such as `char isSymm (int rows, int cols, int Num[rows][cols])`

Answer (score 2):

`Num` is not a "multi-dimensional" array (C doesn't have those), it's an array *of arrays*. So to get an element of it you need to do e.g. `Num[r][c]`.

To explain what happens with `Num[r,c]`, you need to learn about [the *comma operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

The comma operator evaluates both sub-expressions, and throw away the result of the left-hand expression and the result is the result of the right-hand expression. So with `r,c` both `r` and `c` are evaluated, and then the result of `r` is discarded and the result of `r,c` is `c`.

That means your expression `Num[r,c]` is really `Num[c]`. And `Num[c]` is an array, which decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `&Num[c][0]`, and you compare those two pointers.

---

On an unrelated note,

```
else{
    count=count;
}
```

is practically worthless, and you could remove it completely.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access an array of arrays use

```
Num[r][c]
```

The `,` operator which you used does evaluate the part before the `,` but ignores the result. The result of the operator is the value of the second evaluated expression, the one after the `,`.
That is why the compiler tells you that `r` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Change `(Num[r,c]==Num[c,r])` to `(Num[r][c]==Num[c][r])`

Also remove else statement.

```
else{
    count=count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An element in a two-dimensional array is accessed by using the subscripts, i.e., `row index` and `column index` of the array. For example :-

```
int val = a[2][3];
```

The above statement will take the 4th element from the 3rd row of the array.

So in your function `char isSymm (int Num[][4], int rows, int cols)` some changes are to be made:-

```
char isSymm (int Num[][4], int rows, int cols){
    int r,c, count=0;

    for (r=0; r<rows; r++){
        for (c=0; c<cols; c++){
            if (Num[r][c]==Num[c][r]){        // not  Num[r,c]==Num[c,r]
                count=count+1;
            }                                 // not needed count=count; else statement.
        }
    }
    if (count==16){
        return 'y';
    }
    else {
        return 'n';
    }
}
```

The `comma-operator` evaluates both sub-expressions, and throw away the result of the left-hand expression and the result is the result of the right-hand expression. So with r,c both r and c are evaluated, and then the result of r is discarded and the result of `r,c` is `c`.Here it becomes `Num[c]` which is invalid since `Num` is *2-Dimentional* array.

Answer (score 0):

The problametic statement is `Num[r,c]==Num[c,r]` & why its so, its informed by compiler when you run `gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c` as

> error: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
>   [-Werror=unused-value]

In `Num[r,c]` there is **comma** operator between `r` and `c` and comma operator property is that it will solve all argument but consider only right hand operands, so `Num[r,c]` results in `Num[c]` and now you are comparing pointers `Num[c]` and `Num[r]` which will not yield in correct result.

You wanted to check if matrix is `symmetric` or not for that this

`Num[r,c]==Num[c,r]` ==> `Num[r][c] == Num[c][r]`

And since `Num` is symmetric matrix. You should calculate number of `rows` so that it works for any array, not hard coded like `size=4`.

`size=4;` ==>  `size = sizeof(Num)/sizeof(Num[0]);`

And while comparing `Num[r][c]` and `Num[c][r]` the `else` part is useless, better remove it.

```
else{ /* not needed as if if block is false count value doesn't need to change */
    count=count;
}
```